# How do I check if a string contains "(1)" and if it does, increase the number by 1?

Tags: c#, string

If a any given string, at the end contains "(" followed by a number, + ")", i want to increase that value by one. If not Ill just add a "(1)".

Ive tried with something like string.Contains(), but since the value within () can be diffrent i don't know how to always search like this and get the number.

Comment: you can try with regular expression

Comment: get string between( and )..and then convert it to int, increment by one

Comment: Please, provide *some examples*: the *initial* strings and the desired *outcomes*

Comment: You need a `while`-loop, some regex, a `int`-variable and the `.toString()`-method. Try it yourself and ask on specific problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find a parentheses enclosed number at the end of a string, and increase b 1, try this:

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(?<=\()\d+(?=\)$)", match => (int.Parse(match.Value) + 1).ToString());
```

Explanation:

`(?<=\()` is a positive look-behind, which matches an open bracket, but does not include it in the match result.

`\d+` matches one or more digits.

`(?=\)$)` is a positive look-ahead, which matches a closing bracket at the end of the string.

To add a number if none is present, test the match first:

```
string yourString = "A string with no number at the end";
string pattern = @"(?<=\()\d+(?=\)$)";
if (Regex.IsMatch(yourString, pattern))
{
    yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString, pattern, match => (int.Parse(match.Value) + 1).ToString());
}
else
{
    yourString += " (1)";
}
```

Comment: Second this approach. But the int.Parse should use match.Value and the return has to be a string

Answer (score 3):

You can try *regular expressions*: `Match` and `Replace` the desired fragment, e.g.

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "abc",
    "def (123)",
    "pqr (123) def",
    "abs (789) (123)",
  };

  Func<string, string> solution = (line) =>
    Regex.Replace(line, 
      @"\((?<value>[0-9]+)\)$", 
      m => $"({int.Parse(m.Groups["value"].Value) + 1})");

  string demo = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-20} => {solution(test)}"));

  Console.Write(demo);
```

Outcome:

```
abc                  => abc              # no numbers
def (123)            => def (124)        # 123 turned into 124
pqr (123) def        => pqr (123) def    # 123 is not at the end of string
abs (789) (123)      => abs (789) (124)  # 123 turned into 124, 789 spared
```

If we put

```
  Func<string, string> solution = (line) => {
    Match m = Regex.Match(line, @"\((?<value>[0-9]+)\)$");

    return m.Success
      ? line.Substring(0, m.Index) + $"({int.Parse(m.Groups["value"].Value) + 1})"
      : line + " (1)";
  };
```

**Edit:** If we want to put `(1)` if we haven't any match we can try `Match` and replace matched text:

```
abc                  => abc (1)
def (123)            => def (124)
pqr (123) def        => pqr (123) def (1)
abs (789) (123)      => abs (789) (124)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "sampleText";
string pattern = "[(]([0-9]*?)[)]$";

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var m = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
    if (m.Success)
    {
        int value = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value);
        s = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, $"({++value})");
    }
    else
    {
        s += "(1)";
    }

    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have strings such as :

```
string s1 = "foo(12)"
string s2 = "bar(21)"
string s3 = "foobar"
```

And you want to obtain the following:

```
IncrementStringId(s1) == "foo(13)" 
IncrementStringId(s2) == "bar(22)" 
IncrementStringId(s3) == "foobar(1)"
```

you could accomplish this by using the following method

```
public string IncrementStringId(string input)
{
    // The RexEx pattern is looking at the very end of the string for any number encased in paranthesis
    string pattern = @"\(\d*\)$";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    Match match = regex.Match(input);
    if (match.Success)
        if (int.TryParse(match.Value.Replace(@"(", "").Replace(@")", ""), out int index))
            //if pattern in found parse the number detected and increment it by 1
            return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "(" + ++index + ")");
    // In case the pattern is not detected add a (1) to the end of the string
    return input + "(1)";
}
```

Please make sure you are using System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace that includes Regex class.